# R: sort rows, query them and add results as colum

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have an R dataframe with the dimension 32 x 11. For each row I would like to determine the highest value, the second highest, and the third highest value and add these values as extra colums to the initial dataframe (32 x 14). Many thanks in advance!

```
library(car)
data(mtcars)
mtcars
```

Comment: your code doesn't show any research at all... Try a bit, then ask for help if you can't solve it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a function to get the nth highest value for a vector. Then, create a copy of the dataframe, since the second highest value may change as you add more columns. Then apply your function using `apply` and 1 to operate row-wise. I'm not sure what would happen if there are NAs in the data. I haven't tested it...

Something like this...

```
nth_highest <- function(x, n)sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)[n]
tmp <- mtcars
mtcars$highest <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x)nth_highest(x,1))
mtcars$second_highest <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x)nth_highest(x,2))
mtcars$third_highest <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x)nth_highest(x,3))
rm(tmp)
```

Comment: thanks cory! the following works as well `t(apply(mtcars, 1, sort))`